# How to convert array1 to array2?

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I need data structure like `mokeData2` and sources data was like `mokeData`.

How can I convert `mokeData` to `mokeData2` in javascript?

```
const mokeData = ["Friday 07:07:00", "Sunday 12:05:00"];
const mokeData2 = [{ Friday: "07:07:00", Sunday: "12:05:00" }];
```

Comment: Why is the result an array if it is always going to have exactly one element?? What have you done to achieve that goal?

Comment: Familiarize yourself with [how to access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON](/q/11922383/4642212) and how to [create objects](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) and use the available static and instance methods of [`Object`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Static_methods) and [`Array`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods).

Comment: I got data from server was like mokeData and need inject to a table in one column, so that's why I need data structure like mokeData2.

Answer (score 3):

**1)** You can easily achieve the result using [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const mokeData = ["Friday 07:07:00", "Sunday 12:05:00"];
const mokeData2 = [{ Friday: "07:07:00", Sunday: "12:05:00" }];

const result = [Object.fromEntries(mokeData.map((s) => s.split(" ")))];
console.log(result);
```

**2)** You can also use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) here as:

```js
const mokeData = ["Friday 07:07:00", "Sunday 12:05:00"];
const mokeData2 = [{ Friday: "07:07:00", Sunday: "12:05:00" }];

const result = [
  mokeData.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const [key, value] = curr.split(" ");
    acc[key] = value;
    return acc;
  }, {}),
];
console.log(result);
```

Comment: can't use 1) cuz I'm using next.js and 2) was good THANKS ALOT!

Comment: Would you mind If you can [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) my answer if it solved your issue?